# How to solve an issue with vue-transitions being triggered or not through methods

Tags: vue.js, css-animations, vuex, vue-cli, vue-transitions

I am working a study project on `vue-cli` and even though it is a simple project, I am trying to apply some stuff I've been learning.

I have a header with two `routes`:

- Portfolio
- Stocks

I have set a simple `fade` animation once entering into any of these two `routes`.

There are two issues here, and I think both are related. I will get into it after posting the `code` blocks as per listed below.

I will post my code below:

**Header.vue (this is my header)**

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <router-link to="/" class="navbar-brand"><a>Stock Trade</a></router-link>
        <div class="d-inline" @click="toPortfolio">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <router-link :to="{ name: 'portfolio'}"
                             tag="li" class="nav-item nav-link"><a
                             class="text-decoration-none">Portfolio</a></router-link>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" @click="toStocks">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <router-link :to="{name: 'stocks'}"
                             tag="li" class="nav-item nav-link">
                    <a class="text-decoration-none">Stocks</a>
                </router-link>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse end-day">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item nav-link">End Day</li>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline" @click="isDropping = !isDropping">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                       href="#"
                       role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false">
                        Save & Load <span class="dropdown-toggle-no-caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <!-- I must understand why it does not work below-->
                    <div class="dropdown-menu"
                         :class="{show: isDropping}"
                         aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Save Data</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Load Data</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- Got to add a Getter here instead so "DRY" does not happen with the "EUR" assignment-->
            <strong class="navbar-text" style="color: dimgray">Funds: {{$store.state.funds}}</strong>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>
<script>
    import {mapActions} from 'vuex'
    import * as types from '/Users/Dev/WebstormProjects/the-trader-app/src/store/types.js'
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                isDropping: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions({
                toPortfolio: types.COMMIT_TO_PORTFOLIO,
                toStocks: types.COMMIT_TO_STOCKS
            })
        }
    }

</script>
<style scoped>
    a {
        color: dimgray;
    }

    a:hover{
        color: black !important;
    }

    .end-day {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

**Stocks.vue (this is where the stocks would be displayed)**

```
<template>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-sm-around">
        <transition name="fade">
            <div class="wrapper" v-if="showStocks">
                <div class="stock-title">
                    <h4 class="box-headers">BMW</h4>
                    <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock-content">
                    <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                    <button>Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
            <div class="wrapper" v-if="showStocks">
                <div class="stock-title">
                    <h4 class="box-headers">Apple</h4>
                    <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock-content">
                    <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                    <button>Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
            <div class="wrapper" v-if="showStocks">
                <div class="stock-title">
                    <h4 class="box-headers">Facebook</h4>
                    <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock-content">
                    <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                    <button>Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
            <div class="wrapper" v-if="showStocks">
                <div class="stock-title">
                    <h4 class="box-headers">Google</h4>
                    <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock-content">
                    <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                    <button>Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
    import * as types from '/Users/Dev/WebstormProjects/the-trader-app/src/store/types.js';

    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                showStocks: types.GET_STOCKS
            })
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>

    .wrapper {
        border: solid lightgray 1px;
        width: 500px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    }

    .stock-title {
        background-color: lightskyblue;
        color: royalblue;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 7px 0 0 20px;
    }

    .box-headers {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px -1px 10px 10px;
    }

    p {
        align-self: flex-end;
    }

    .stock-content {
        display: flex;
    }

    input {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    button {
        background-color: royalblue;
        color: white;
        padding: 0 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        justify-self: center;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    ::placeholder {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .fade-enter {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .fade-enter-active {
        transition: opacity 2s;
    }

    .fade-leave-active {
        transition: opacity 2s;
        opacity: 0;
    }


</style>
```

**Portfolio.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-sm-around">
        <transition name="fade">
        <div class="wrapper" v-if="showPortfolio">
            <div class="stock-title">
                <h4 class="box-headers">BMW</h4>
                <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stock-content">
                <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                <button>Sell</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
        <div class="wrapper" v-if="showPortfolio">
            <div class="stock-title">
                <h4 class="box-headers">Apple</h4>
                <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stock-content">
                <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                <button>Sell</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
        <div class="wrapper" v-if="showPortfolio">
            <div class="stock-title">
                <h4 class="box-headers">Facebook</h4>
                <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stock-content">
                <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                <button>Sell</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
        <div class="wrapper" v-if="showPortfolio">
            <div class="stock-title">
                <h4 class="box-headers">Google</h4>
                <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stock-content">
                <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                <button>Sell</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
    import * as types from '/Users/Dev/WebstormProjects/the-trader-app/src/store/types.js';

    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                showPortfolio: types.GET_PORTFOLIO
            })
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

    .wrapper {
        border: solid lightgray 1px;
        width: 500px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc
    }

    .stock-title {
        background-color: #ffbf00;
        color: indianred;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 7px 0 0 20px;
    }

    .box-headers {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px -1px 10px 10px;
    }

    .stock-content {
        display: flex;
    }

    p {
        align-self: flex-end;
    }

    input {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    button {
        background-color: indianred;
        color: white;
        padding: 0 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        justify-self: center;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    ::placeholder {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .fade-enter {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .fade-enter-active {
        transition: opacity 2s;
    }

    .fade-leave-active {
        transition: opacity 2s;
        opacity: 0;
    }
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import {store} from "./store/store";
import {routes} from "./routes";

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

export const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if(savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition
    }
    if (to.hash) {
      return {selector: to.hash}
    }
    return {x: 0, y: 0};
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
router,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import altAnims from "@/store/modules/altAnims";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
      sharesValue: {
         BMW: 1,
         Apple: 0,
         FaceBook: 0,
         Google: 0
      },
      user:{
         funds: 1000,
         shares: {
            BMW: 0,
            Apple: 0,
            FaceBook: 0,
            Google: 0
         }
      }
   },
   modules: {
      altAnims
   }
});
```

**types.js**

```
// Getters
export const GET_PORTFOLIO = 'portfolio/shared';
export const GET_STOCKS = 'stocks/shared';
//Mutations
export const MUTATE_PORTFOLIO = 'shared/SET_PORTFOLIO';
export const MUTATE_STOCKS = 'shared/SET_STOCKS';
//Actions
export const COMMIT_TO_PORTFOLIO = 'shared/ALTERNATE_PORTFOLIO';
export const COMMIT_TO_STOCKS = 'shared/ALTERNATE_STOCKS';
```

**altAnims.js (this is where I fool around with this animation)**

```
import * as types from '../types';

const state = {
    showStock: false,
    showPortfolio: false
};

const getters = {
    [types.GET_PORTFOLIO]: state => {
        return state.showPortfolio
    },
    [types.GET_STOCKS]: state => {
        return state.showStock
    }
};

const mutations = {
    [types.MUTATE_PORTFOLIO]: state => {
        state.showPortfolio = true;
        state.showStock = false
    },
    [types.MUTATE_STOCKS]: state => {
        state.showStock = true;
        state.showPortfolio = false
    }
};

const actions = {
[types.COMMIT_TO_PORTFOLIO]: ({commit}) => {
    commit(types.MUTATE_PORTFOLIO);
},
    [types.COMMIT_TO_STOCKS]: ({commit}) => {
    commit(types.MUTATE_STOCKS);
    }
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
}
```

**First Issue**

The first thing I tried to do was to create the simple `fade` animation that you guys can see on both `Stocks.vue` & `Portfolio.vue` files, that should get triggered by a `@click` event on `Headers.vue`.

Well, the first issue is that for some reason, when I reload the page and trigger **the `@click` `event` for the first time** into any of both `Profile.vue` or `Stocks.vue` the `animation` does not occur. But after switching in between each other it starts to work.

I do not understand why it does not work at the first click, as you can se on `altAnims.js` the `state` of both items is set originally to `false`.

```
const state = {
    showStock: false,
    showPortfolio: false
};
```

Then once committing the `action` of `mutating` the `state`, as you can see on the progression at `altAnims.js` inverting their `Boolean` statements, on the first click `v-if` should be reading a `getter` with the `state` of `false` to `true`, as you can see what the `@click` event does at `Header.vue`

**Second Issue**

Even though I did not resolve this issue at the first place, I tried to move ahead.

This is what I have tried to do @ `Portfolio.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-sm-around">
        <transition name="fade">
        <div class="wrapper" v-if="revealBMW">
            <div class="stock-title">
                <h4 class="box-headers">BMW</h4>
                <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stock-content">
                <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                <button>Sell</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
        <div class="wrapper" v-if="revealApple">
            <div class="stock-title">
                <h4 class="box-headers">Apple</h4>
                <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stock-content">
                <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                <button>Sell</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
        <div class="wrapper" v-if="revealFaceBook">
            <div class="stock-title">
                <h4 class="box-headers">Facebook</h4>
                <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stock-content">
                <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                <button>Sell</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
        <div class="wrapper" v-if="revealGoogle">
            <div class="stock-title">
                <h4 class="box-headers">Google</h4>
                <p class="box-headers" style="font-size: 13px">(Price: 20 EUR)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stock-content">
                <input type="text" class="mr-auto" placeholder="How many shares?">
                <button>Sell</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
    import * as types from '/Users/Dev/WebstormProjects/the-trader-app/src/store/types.js';

    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                showPortfolio: types.GET_PORTFOLIO
            })
        },
        methods: {
            revealBMW(){
                if(this.$store.state.sharesValue.BMW > 0) {
                    return this.showPortfolio
                }
            },
            revealApple(){
                if(this.$store.state.sharesValue.Apple > 0) {
                    return this.showPortfolio                }
            },
            revealFaceBook(){
                if(this.$store.state.sharesValue.FaceBook > 0) {
                    return this.showPortfolio                }
            },
            revealGoogle(){
                if(this.$store.state.sharesValue.Google > 0) {
                    return this.showPortfolio                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

    .wrapper {
        border: solid lightgray 1px;
        width: 500px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc
    }

    .stock-title {
        background-color: #ffbf00;
        color: indianred;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 7px 0 0 20px;
    }

    .box-headers {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px -1px 10px 10px;
    }

    .stock-content {
        display: flex;
    }

    p {
        align-self: flex-end;
    }

    input {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    button {
        background-color: indianred;
        color: white;
        padding: 0 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        justify-self: center;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    ::placeholder {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .fade-enter {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .fade-enter-active {
        transition: opacity 2s;
    }

    .fade-leave-active {
        transition: opacity 2s;
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
```

I have added some `methods` so I would only display the containers which had a number of shares more then 0 at `altAnims.js`'s state every time I would enter this route. In order to test this I have hardcoded `BMW: 1` and the final result is that the `animation` stopped working and the BMW shares `container` is also not responding to my `methods`.

I am not sure if this would be a good practice, maybe placing these methods in the `computed` instead, or something totally different that I am missing.

Sorry for such a long question, full of blocks of code. I was trying to be as detailed as possible.

I would like to get help on **both issues**

P.S - One thought I have just had is if this could work using `templates` for each `container` that would like to load in this case. I did not try it, but would it be possible?

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: Mate, this is just too much code. You should [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue...ideally on site like Codesandbox so peoplel can run it and experiment. Some notes...why you doing transitions in so complicated way? You are using Vue Router and still I don't see `<router-view>` anywhere. Look [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html) how to do transitions between routes without `v-if`'s, Vuex and all that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just too many things to write about and [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be better place to do that but....

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-solve-an-issue-with-vue-transitions-being-triggered-or-not-through-methods-puuku) you can find my take on the problem. Things to look for:

1. Transitions using `<route-view>` without vuex and other complicated stuff - tuned using `appear` so it transitions on initial render and `mode="out-in"` (just try to remove it to see the effect)
2. Better store state - don't use company names as object keys, not every company name is valid JS identifier
3. Rewrote `Portfolio` and `Stocks` component to use `v-for` for rendering array data from store

### Transitions with Vue Router

```html
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in" appear>
  <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"/>
</transition>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for all of this work in helping me out! It looks much neater. Now I am trying to figure out how to limit the content being passed in the ```v-for``` trying to pass a ```method``` in ```v-for``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472978/can-i-use-the-index-argument-in-v-for-nested-in-a-method . I did not know about Codereview! I will make sure to never repeat this mess I have done here, sir! THanks very very much!