# Can I use the 'index' argument in 'v-for' nested in a 'method'?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I need to use index on a `v-for` but on the same level as the `directive` itself in order to `mutate` the state being shown.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="share in sharesPurchased()" :key="share">
      <div>
        <h4>This is some content</h4>
        <p style="border: solid 1px">{{share.count}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        shares: [
          {id: 'BMW', count: 1},
          {id: 'Ford', count: 0},
          {id:'Apple', count: 10}
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      sharesPurchased() {
// I want to use this at the v-for level to limit content view
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I want to limit what is being displayed in this iteration so I only show content with a `count > 0` i.e: `shares[i].count > 0`

The result of my intent as per stated above should have `<p style="border: solid 1px">{{share.count}}</p>` displaying just `1` as only `this.shares[0].count` is `>` then `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: based on your need to use it, this is clearly an X-Y problem. You should be using computed properties instead:

```
computed: {
    filteredSharesByCount: function() {
        return this.shares.filter(share => share.count > 0);
    }
}
```

You can then reference it as such in your template:

---

Outdated answer:

The [index is accessible as the second optional argument](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) in the `v-for` binding:

> `v-for` also supports an optional second argument for the index of the current item.

ie:

```
<div v-for="(share, idx) in sharesPurchased(shares)" :key="share">
```

Then, within the loop you can simply use `idx` if you want a method to have access to the index.

Comment: Yep, I understand that it is there, but when I try to use it within the ```method``` eslint will tell me that ```idx``` was defined but never used...

Comment: Try `:index="idx"`, or `v-index` i forget which.  Edit, or if you're not using it at all, try remove it from the `()`

Comment: You need to pass index to the method first. In your code there isn’t any indication where you plan to use it, so it’s not clear what your intended use case is.

Comment: Instead of showing all the content, I want to limit the content to whatever share that has a count higher then 0, instead of displaying it all as on a regular ```v-for=share in shares```. I will remove the ```filters``` there in order try and be more clear on my intent

Comment: Thanks, Terry. I get what you are doing at this ```computed``` ```function``` but I still seem confused. I should now use this ```computed``` function at the ```div``` element? ```<div v-for="share in filteredSharesByCount()"
         :key="share">``` It did not work and what are you suggesting to be returned + arg being passed @ ```sharesPurchased()``` in this case?

Comment: See my updated answer: you should be filtering based on `this.shares`. And yes, you use the computed property for the `v-for` binding

Comment: thanks! I was committing a silly mistake of entering the ```computed``` method with the empty ```()``` besides it. Now I've got it! Thanks so much for your patience! Cheers!